# Display passed parameter in subreport when no match exists

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

I have a report with one subreport. The subreport is passed a variable, @staffid, to match against a table of employees. If there is no matching staffid, I need the parameter value (@staffid) to display in the subreport.  I need to check to see if DisplayName exists for the subreport, and if not, show @staffid in textbox that would ordinarily show DisplayName if there were a match.
Below is a screenshot of the report output right now, but I need to fill in the empty user space with the value passed from the main report if there is no match.
[image]

I'm looking for an expression to use in the textbox that basically says, =IIF(ISNULL(Field.DisplayName.Value)),@staffid,Field.DisplayName.Value), but I can't find a combination that works.

Answer (score 0):

Please pass "Parameteres!staffid.value"  instead of "@staffid" in sub-report expression as @staffid is a parameter defined in sub-report

Comment: I've tried =iif(ISNOTHING(Fields!DisplayName.Value),Parameters!StaffId.Value,Fields!DisplayName.Value); also ISNULL in place of ISNOTHING; checked LEN to the Fields!DisplayName.Value.  Nothing works.

Comment: Check like this:
=iif(Fields!DisplayName.Value IS Nothing,Parameters!StaffId.Value,Fields!Display‌​Name.Value);

Comment: No go.  I think the  problem is that the subreport is returning nothing at all, so I need to find a way to display the StaffId from the main report in the subreport cell when the subreport is null.